# Text is glitching when reached vertical limit on drag

Tags: java, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make draggable text that can only go vertically on the screen. However I have set a limit for the text so that is doesn't go out of the screen. Here is what I am expecting:

[image: Expectation]

But it is glitching when it reaches it's limit. When dragged down, it snaps to it's bottom limit before reaching it. Then sometimes it stays still at the bottom limit and get's wiped when dragged down. And when dragged up slowly, it crosses it's top vertical limit as shown in this clip:

[image: Reality]

## Code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/draggableText"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Draggable Text"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.android.draganddrop;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewGroup rootLayout;
    private int yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root);
        LinearLayout textContainer = findViewById(R.id.textContainer);
        textContainer.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    }

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            // Log.d("yourtag", "Y: " + Y);     <== Use this line to track the text's coordinates in the Logcat
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - yDelta;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    if (Y < 75) {             // This is where I set the top vertical limit
                        view.setY(75);
                    } else if (Y > 1150) {    // This is where I set the bottom vertical limit
                        view.setY(1150);
                    }

                    break;
            }
            rootLayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors:** None

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In a world with ConstraintLayout, there is no need for RelativeLayout.

You can achieve the desired effect [using MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout).

The code below is a modified version of the sample code [here](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/62038221f1346652d44ebbcd539ba025e78706c1/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/xml/scene_02.xml) and [here](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/62038221f1346652d44ebbcd539ba025e78706c1/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/layout/motion_02_basic.xml).

[image]

Layout XML:

```xml
<!-- Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_02">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="64dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:text="Draggable Text"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MotionScene referenced above (`app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_02"`):

```xml
<!-- Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 -->
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/button"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/button">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/end"
        motion:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start">

        <Constraint android:id="@id/button">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                 />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```